# conditional tags- how to use with shortcodes

Tags: pages, shortcode, gallery, conditional-tags

I have a [salon website](http://parlourdc.com/wp) with a gallery page wherein the user must first select a stylist prior to viewing their individual gallery.

I planned on using NextGen to house the images in stylist specific galleries, and using the NextGen shortcodes(ex: `[nggallery id=1]`) to determine which gallery gets shown on the specific page.

After doing a bit of research, I think WP's conditional tags (I'm thinking `is_page( # )`) might be the best route to take for this, I'm just not sure how to integrate the conditional tags to specify/define the page and the NextGen shortcodes.

Any tips, help, advice, etc. is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to understand your question, but you have to read more wordpress/nextgen documentation.

What you need to do exactly? Can you be more specific?

I think, that if you create a set of pages (for each stylist) and use the respective shortcode of the gallery in the content, this will work fine.

ex: in the page REBECCA HAEHNLE (page_id=29) use `[nggallery id=ref_stylist_galery]`

On the mother page (gallery), use the album shortcode (create an album with all the stylists galleries in order you want) `[album id=ref_album_id template=extend]`

I think it will do the trick :)

In other words, you can do something like this in your **page.php** template:

```
if( is_page(ID_OF_SPECIFIC_PAGE) ) {
  // make your stuff here
  echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id='.$my_id.']');
} else {
  // output standard content here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
In gallery.php I have inserted the following: 

`<div class="gallery">
    <?php     
        if( is_page( 29 ) ) {
        // make your stuff here
        echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id='1']');
        } else {
         // output standard content here
        }
  
        <?php endif; ?>  
    </div><!-- end gallery -->`

In WP Page content field I have `[nggallery id=1]`.

Making those changes has lead to a completely [white page](http://parlourdc.com/wp/rebecca-h). Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: in config.php in wordpress root: change to define('WP_DEBUG', true); and you will now see php error output on screen. :)

Comment: the template in your theme: /nggallery/gallery.php is to output HTML markup... and if you put allready the shortcode in your post, you don´t need call it again.
he is allready in page(29)

Comment: oh, debugging. There was an unnecessary `endif` in the php. Thank you for your help!